# Create jsonb data with SQL query (postgresql), then create new column with this jsonb data

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I want to add a new column to the table with jsonb data(query data from other columns  ).
Current table:

| student_id | first_name | last_name | data_lable1 | data_value1 | data_lable2 | data_value2 | data_lable3 | data_value3 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Steve | Lee | address code | 106 | Grade | 8 | Pick up | true | … |
| 1235 | John | Lee | Transferred | true | Grade | 7 | Pick up | false | … |

After query data from *data_lable1, data_value1, data_lable2, data_value2, data_lable3, data_value3*, then add the jsonb data to new column student data:

| student_id | first_name | last_name | data_lable1 | data_value1 | data_lable2 | data_value2 | data_lable3 | data_value3 | student data | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Steve | Lee | area code | 106 | Grade | 8 | Pick up | true | {“area code”:”106”, “Grade”:”8”, “Pick up”: “true”} | … |
| 1235 | John | Lee | Transferred | true | Grade | 7 | Pick up | false | {“Transferred”:”true”, “Grade”:”8”, “Pick up”: “false”} | … |

I am wondering if this is doable with SQL query. If the answer is yes, how?

**NOTE:**

1. Above table is made up, just as an example.
2. *data_lable** and *data_value** could be null

******* **Update 1** *********
I am using *jsonb_build_object*(suggested by @Nnaemeka Daniel John) to build the jsonb object first.

```
select jsonb_build_object(CONCAT('',student.data_lable1,''),  CONCAT('',student.data_value1,''), CONCAT('',student.data_lable2,''),  CONCAT('',student.data_value2,''), CONCAT('',student.data_lable3,''),  CONCAT('',student.data_value3,'')) from student;
```

I am getting a result, but seems in some cases the order could be wrong. Is there a way that I can set the data set sequence as the original sequence in the table?

```
{“Pick up”: “true”, “area code”:”106”, “Grade”:”8”}
```

Which really should be like below

```
{“area code”:”106”, “Grade”:”8”, “Pick up”: “true”}
```

BTW, I have to use CONCAT('',column_name,''), otherwise will get

```
ERROR: argument 1: key must not be null
```

Comment: Sure, what have you tried? Create the json and update your target table. See the manual about how to create a json: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `jsonb_build_object` function you can build a jsonb object from the table columns for each row in table:

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET student_data = jsonb_build_object(
    data_label1, data_value1,
    data_label2, data_value2,
    data_label3, data_value3
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer from @Nnaemeka.  Only thing needed beforehand is to add the jsonb column first: ALTER TABLE student
ADD column student_data jsonb;